# autorefresh edittext android from Mysql

Tags: java, android, json

I'm new to android, I'm building simple app on eclipse (android), I have two EditText in android, and I have one table in MySql, 
now I want to make autorefresh after inserting data in my table at MySQl, how can I do this ?

Comment: Can you just query the database for the row you just inserted? I have not used Android SDK, but this is something I have done when working with MySQL in other languages.

Comment: what do you mean with "Can you just query the database for the row you just inserted" ?

Comment: Do you have an SQL query interface? I bet you do... You could run a `SELECT` statement on your database like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=value_you_just_inserted` where 'table' is your table name, and 'column' is your column name.

Comment: I've do like that 
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('joe', $link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

/* grab the posts from the db */
$query = "SELECT lattitude, longitude FROM tracking";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query);

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$data = "{joel:".json_encode($rows)."}";
echo $data;
?>

Comment: That should do it.... What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague as to what you're trying to do.  Are you pulling values from the edittext fields to place into the SQL table?

You can query the database for the most recent row that was entered into the table and then parse your information that way.  You can specify something like "DESC _id" and grab the latest row that way.

This may help out with some general SQL questions: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android